# Greasemonkey access violation: unsafeWindow cannot call GM_getResourceText

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I recently started to get this error when trying to read a resource file using `GM_getResourceText("filename.txt")` after upgrading my browser to *Firefox 30*, if it matters.

I believe it's a bug but I can't find anything about it, because in *Firefox 29* it worked perfectly. And even now, it worked a few times, without changing anything, just refreshing the page. And also, I don't even use `unsafeWindow`!

My script looks something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @resource    file file.txt
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==

if(!isOnIframe()) {
    test();
}

function isOnIframe() {
    return !(window.self === window.top);
}

function test() {
    var file = GM_getResourceText(name);
}
```

**Edit**: I noticed it doesn't work on *Facebook* and on other sites it works. Did the changed something? How can I find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm, Scriptish 0.1.11 (GM fork) doesn't work with Firefox 30 on Linux.
Same issue was reported with Fox version 20.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=844406

Internal function apiLeakCheck checks for user space code (not sandboxed) on the stack and seems to fail in Fox 30 again.

Official latest Scriptish version is 0.1.11, but there's a version 0.1.12 available just yet.
https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/scriptish/versions/

This fixes the problem for me. I don't know the current state of Greasymonkey (pre)releases.

Comment: I found some bug reports that shows the same problem in _FF 20_ like you said, but I didn't think it reappeared in _FF 30_

Comment: At least it seems to base on a very similar reason. The problem occurs in the function apiLeakCheck while trying to parse the stack for calls by website codes. In version 20 it was due to an inaccessible stack. I don't know and I haven't done further investigation if the current bug is exactly identical, however, the bug is occurring at the same internal code point.

Comment: Do you have any idea when it's going to be solved? Or why it's sometimes working? Or even in the same script some calls pass, and some don't.

Comment: No, but the new Scriptish version 0.1.12 did not make any trouble by now.